# Unity 5 PlayerPrefs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, save, scene

I tried in very much ways, but I really can't figure it out. This is a level lock/unlock system made by me. On my PC works perfectlly, but when I test it on my android smartphone nothing works. Why ? If I will use PlayerPrefs will work ? How I should use PlayerPrefs ? Because I tried in very much ways and no result.

Here is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class LevelLockSystem : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject unlockLevel2;
    public GameObject unlockLevel3;
    public GameObject unlockLevel4;
    public GameObject unlockLevel5;
    public GameObject unlockLevel6;
    public GameObject unlockLevel7;
    public GameObject unlockLevel8;
    public GameObject unlockLevel9;
    public GameObject unlockLevel10;

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void LockAllLevels()
    {
        unlockLevel2.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel3.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel4.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel5.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel6.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel7.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel8.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel9.SetActive(true);
        unlockLevel10.SetActive(true);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel2()
    {
        unlockLevel2.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel3()
    {
        unlockLevel3.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel4()
    {
        unlockLevel4.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel5()
    {
        unlockLevel5.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel6()
    {
        unlockLevel6.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel7()
    {
        unlockLevel7.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel8()
    {
        unlockLevel8.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel9()
    {
        unlockLevel9.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void UnlockLevel10()
    {
        unlockLevel10.SetActive(false);
    }

}
```

Comment: install adb (from Android dev tools). use it to connect to your device (using a usb cable). then use logcat to capture the stack trace and the error that caused it. then dig into your code at that line - I see nothing wrong w/ what you have shown us.

Comment: I know is nothing wrong ... It works perfectlly ... Here is the prove https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AyKTx0WvHjs

Comment: I guess I don't understand then - what is your question? If its working in the editor but not on your device, you need to capture the error message from the device.

Comment: Now is working :D ! Thank you ! :D